# Error Installing fake_useragent in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am unable to install fake_useragent in python.

getting this error:

> pip install fake-useragent
>
> ```
>        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `pip install` commands, you run them from the command line (i.e. command prompt, Terminal).

When in the shell, you use `import module` to import the module you installed.

From the looks of the error, what you tried to do was run a command in python's shell, which was originally meant for a command line.

---

## How to install modules using PyCharm:

- Press `ctrl + alt + s` to bring up the settings.
- Click on `Project Interpreter`

  [image]
- Click the `+` on the right-hand side

  [image]
- Search for your desired package (i.e. the same name you would type after `pip install`)

  [image]
- *OPTIONAL* Specify the desired version
- Hit `Install Package`

  [image]
- Wait for it to finish installing, and you should be done!

Comment: So, how do I install this? 
I am using Pycharm as the editor.

Comment: @HRITHIKJAIN Edited.